# python version on python server

Tags: python, server, version

I use pyenv to manage python versions. I'm using Python 3.4.1 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64), but in python cgi running on python server, python version seems to become 2.7.10. 
How can I fix this to use version 3.4.1 on python server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `python3 --version` on the server, what version is it ? I'm making the assumption that you are using a newer version of Linux on the server which might be shipped with both a Python 2.7.x and Python 3.x version.

If not, you'll have to download and install it yourself, preferably into it's own location, as you do not wish to override the system version of Python that can be used for things such as package management.